# What is the maximum number of emails that can be sent in outlook

Tags: outlook

I need to send 10k mails. What is the maximum limit that outlook(professional account) allows?

Answer (score 0):

A brief search of [their TOS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/servicesagreement) does not yield a hard number. They do however state in their Code of Conduct:

> a. By agreeing to these Terms, you’re agreeing that, when using the Services, you will follow these rules:
>   ...
>   iii. Don’t send spam. Spam is unwanted or unsolicited bulk email, postings, contact requests, SMS (text messages), or instant messages.
>   ...

Sending 10k emails in a short time (even a week might be considered "short" in this regard) may very well trigger inbuilt spam detecting (both by microsoft and the e-mail providers of your recipients, even if the emails are **not** unwanted/unsolicited).

I can only strongly advise you to directly contact a service representative from outlook/microsoft and clear things with them beforehand, to avoid any unpleasant surprises or legal hassles.

Comment: At a time, what is the maximum number of mails I can send? How to divide it?

Comment: As I said before, you best directly contact their support / service representative. I *guess* they have some kind of internal metric to flag **suspicous** activity (e.g. bulk sending e-mail) but I doubt they will tell you exact numbers in order to stop people from trying to game the system. That said, if your purposes are **legitimate** you should have **no problems** explaining your situation to a **representative**, who will be able to give you detailed information. (And if your purposes are **not legitimate**... reconsider what you are doing; there are better, honest ways to earn money)